# Compare string literal command line parameters in C

Tags: c, linux, parameter-passing

I need my program to run this way `./src c 2345 or ./src s 345`, whereby the first character hs to be either c or s and second an integer. The program should throw an usage error if there's any less parameters and also any charcter other than c or s. Here's my code

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int num_of_connections = 0, client_sockfd;
    int max_sockfd, master_socket;

    fd_set socket_collection, read_collection;

    // Check validity of the user input
    if(argc < 3) {
        if((strcmp(argv[2], "s") != 0) || (strcmp(argv[2], "c") != 0)){
            fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./src <s/c> <port>\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    }
```

When I enter one argument I get a segmentation fault. Also it doesnt identify the C or S parameter. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You get a segmentation fault because there's no such thing as `argv[2]` if you only enter one argument... you should first check against `argc` to see whether the number of arguments is **exactly** what your program needs. If so (and only then) go ahead and check what they are. Of course then any of the above two checks fail, print out the usage message.

Answer (score 1):

`if(argc < 3) {` does not make sense if you want exactly two parameters. In the inner `if` block you are confusion `||` (logical or)  with `&&` (logical and).

In your invocation example `./src s 345` the character is the first argument, so probably `argv[2]` should read `argv[1]`.

```
if ((argc != 3) || ((strcmp(argv[1], "s") != 0) &&
                    (strcmp(argv[1], "c") != 0))) {
    fprintf(…);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Note: all parentheses in this `if (…)` condition are optional, because of C's operator precedence. I put them for readability.

Comment: This has the same issues if I enter anything other than s or c it still works.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that `main` has a very specific convention: the `argv` array has `argc+1` members, with the last being `NULL` and the others being non-null distinct pointers to zero-terminated strings.

So if `argc` is 1 (e.g. if your run `./src` alone) or 2, `argv[2]` is `NULL` and you cannot pass it to  `strcmp`

You can call `strcmp(argv[2],"s")` *only* when `argc>=3`

BTW, I would suggest to use [getopt(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) or preferably (on Linux only) `getopt_long` and to accept the `--help` and `--version` arguments, per GNU [conventions](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Command_002dLine-Interfaces).

Also, compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`) and use the `gdb` debugger. It would be faster for you to use `gdb` than to ask here and wait for replies.

Comment: The `if(argc < 3)` is clearly a mistake, please read the invocation example.

Comment: `if(argc < 3) <exit>` is correct, but needed to be a preliminary and separate test. The `strcmp` comparisons could then follow if `argc >= 3`.